# Why is my AlarmManager firing off instantly?

Tags: android, time, calendar, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm trying to build an alarm application. I had the alarm working before and I was able to set the different times and the alarm would go off appropriately. I then changed the layout of the ChangeAlarmActivity to a TableLayout and now it won't work? I didn't touch the code. Here is how I set the alarm:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, (int)alarm.getID(),
        alarmIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
System.out.println("Alarm time: " + hour + ":" + min);
Calendar alarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
//alarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);  
alarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);        
//alarmCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        alarmCal.getTimeInMillis(),
        pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possibly because your hour and minute are in the past.

Let's say that it is 16:07 hours (using 24 hour time) in your current time zone, and you execute this code with `hour` as `3` and `min` as `27`. 03:27 was in the past, and hence the alarm fires immediately.

After making your two `set()` calls, see if the time is earlier than now, and if so, `add()` one day.

Comment: I suppose a if(alarmCal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) would suffice?

Comment: Thank you, gonna try that now :)

Comment: I was misled by the parameter name `triggerAtMillis` and thought it is the millisceonds **to** the time and I was passing the timespan in millis