# Alarm is running immediately after it is created

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to play a ringtone at exactly at 7 PM everyday but it is playing ringtone immediately after its pending intent is registering broadcast.

I called the service in the foreground on a button click and created pending intent there in onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

    startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID,
            buildForegroundNotification("DummyApp"));

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60*24;
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),
            interval, pendingIntent);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, DataProcessor.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 0,
            alarmIntent, 0);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Now I am playing a ringtone on receiving this broadcast in DataProcessor class the on Receive method of Data Processor class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx,Intent intent) {


    playRIng(ctx);

 }
```

But when I run this code,click the button,service is created but alarm is fired immediately after the AlarmService is called and ringtone is played also.How it is possible because I am giving the exact 7 O clock time when registering broadcast.?
Googled a lot but found the same code only and nothing else.Every code is able to play the ringtone on the time but it also plays the ringtone immediately after the broadcast is registered.

Comment: Try these two answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358984/why-is-my-android-alarm-manager-firing-instantly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201148/why-is-my-alarmmanager-firing-off-instantly

Comment: Because you set it for ... when? if the current time is already past, the alarm will fire immediately. Try setting the date also (today or tomorrow, depending on the current time).

Comment: @DerGolem Can you explain please

Comment: Say today's hour is 20:00. Then set the date for tomorrow at 19:00. Else set the date for today at 19:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the example at developers website understanding the samplecode available there.May be there is some programming mistake in your code but the sample code available there is working exactly you want.

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#type)

Comment: Thank you so much @Anarkali.You saved me.The way I wrote the code for alarm was not correct.Using this I corrected my mistakes and now its working great.
El_Mochiq your condition was true and appropriate for making the alarm fire exactly at 19.Thankyou also. :)

Comment: Hey can i get your code. please

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use a condition?:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx,Intent intent) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

if(hour==19) 
 {
    playRIng(ctx);
 }

 }
```

Comment: I think this might work.Let me try to run this.Thanks a lot for this answer. :)

Comment: @Andhadhundh Pitaii, could you acept my answer pls?

Comment: Sorry it worked but I am not sure it will work in my complete application.There are some problems related to broadcast receiver,I don't know whether they are related to these particular lines.because at first time it was successful in broadcasting exactly at 19 but mostly my broadcast is not working.when everything goes fine and your code also works fine with all conditions I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you ran that code at 9pm you would be telling the AlarmManager that the intent should have been run for the first time 2 hours ago.

You need to check if the Calendar time is behind the current time.
If it is you need to add a day to the calendar so that it first triggers tomorrow at 7pm.

Something like this might work:

```
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    // Not needed
    // c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    // ** Add this **
    // Check if the Calendar 7pm is in the past
    if (c.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // It is so tell it to run tomorrow instead

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, DataProcessor.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

Comment: c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  Why is this line for?Is it not setting the time of c to current time?

Comment: Just calling Calendar.getInstance() will give you the current time. There's no need to set it with setTimeInMillis(). The issue with your code is you may be telling the AlarmManager that the alarm should have been triggered in the past, so it happens as soon as you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, Play with hour & mintue.

Note: Please check your time formate. In my case it's 24 hr formate

Example:

```
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   //for 12 hr formate user int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    //Log.e("time",""+hour+":"+minute);

    if (hour == 10 && minute == 0 ) {

     }
```